# Folder property showing wrong size

Tags: windows-xp

I know it will sound awkward but I have a folder on my machine which contains 4 files of total size hardly 4 KB. But When I right click and open the folder property, to my surprise the total size is shown as 426 TB. This is actually interesting as my total hard disk size is 250 GB. I have already scanned my whole system and there is not any trace of virus.

I have also tried to delete the folder but it is not allowing me to delete it as well.

I am so confused.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a disk error. Run CHKDSK and it should fix the size problem. Then you should be able to delete it.